# The limit of $(1-\pi/2)\tan x$ as $x\to\pi/2$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow  \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\tan(x)$$
I'm trying to putting  $x = t+\pi/2$ zero is in denominator

Comment: I guess the first factor is $\color{red}{x}-\dfrac\pi2$?

Comment: no, just (1-pi/2)

Comment: In that case, this is no indeterminate form. Why did change your post then?

Comment: Normal Human made changes, ask him

Comment: @NormalHuman Be careful. Although you edited the question to what is clearly intended by the original question author, it is explicitly not what the OP has asked or clarified in the comments here. I am putting the question back into the intended (less interesting) form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $x-\dfrac\pi2=u$ $\enspace(u\to 0$ when $x\to\dfrac\pi2$), and note
$$\Bigl(x-\frac\pi2\Bigr)\tan x=-\frac u{\tan u}\sim_0-\frac uu=-1.$$

Comment: There was a small typo in my answer (a minus sign was missing);

Answer (score 0):

rewrite $tan(x)=\frac {sin(x)}{cos(x)}$ and use L'Hopital rule.